# Angular-UI Bootstrap Datepicker inside tab with ng-required attribute not working

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to get the Bootstrap datepicker working under a tab and it seems like some issues with it using with ng-required attribute. It is not updating the model value. Seems like a bug but not sure. If you take out ng-required attribute everything would work just fine.

Any help would be helpful. 
plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NFcm0Bpu0y45LsrzVtpr?p=preview

```
 $scope.data = { 
      opened: false, 
      record: 
      { 
        "Date of Birth": "2005-10-29T00:00:00" 
      } 

<form name="mainForm" novalidate>
            <div class="container" ng-form="subForm">
                <tabset>
                    <tab>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': subForm['test'].$invalid}">
                                    <label class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
                                    <p class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="test" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" ng-model="data.record['Date of Birth']" is-open="data.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" ng-required="true" />
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="false" ng-click="openDate($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </tab>
                </tabset>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working with Angular 1.2.16. The problem is when using with Angualar 1.3.0. Logged an issue with Angualr-ui.